Almalinux 8 | Unable to detect release version
Good Day
I have three Almalinux 8 servers, and they all three are running on 8.9. Out of the three, two seem to fail when I run yum/dnf update with the following error:
yum update
Unable to detect release version (use '--releasever' to specify release version)
AlmaLinux $releasever - BaseOS                                                                                                                                 49  B/s | 273  B     00:05    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'baseos':
  - Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.almalinux.org/mirrorlist/$releasever/baseos (IP: 52.200.132.63)
  - Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.almalinux.org/mirrorlist/$releasever/baseos (IP: 44.193.167.250)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'baseos': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.almalinux.org/mirrorlist/$releasever/baseos (IP: 52.200.132.63)

Running it with yum update --releasever=8.9 works fine, after I have disabled a few repos that complain.
I have compared these two servers with the working server and all repos and so, but they are all three configured EXACTLY the same.
cat /etc/redhat-release
AlmaLinux release 8.9 (Midnight Oncilla)

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="AlmaLinux"
VERSION="8.9 (Midnight Oncilla)"
ID="almalinux"
ID_LIKE="rhel centos fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.9"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="AlmaLinux 8.9 (Midnight Oncilla)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
LOGO="fedora-logo-icon"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://almalinux.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.almalinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.almalinux.org/"

ALMALINUX_MANTISBT_PROJECT="AlmaLinux-8"
ALMALINUX_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8.9"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="AlmaLinux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.9"

I have tried following this: https://github.com/AlmaLinux/almalinux-deploy/issues/123#issuecomment-1052123001 but I don't have files /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo and /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-AppStream.repo and even if I did, this would just disable it, which is not ideally what we want to do in this case.
And as mentioned when we run yum update --releasever=8.9 some repos complain, which means we need to disable them, and incline they would never update accordingly.
I would appreciate any assistance in this regard, thank you.
EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I have also commented the mirror URL and uncommented the correct baseurl in the almalinux.rep file and now it throws:
yum update
Unable to detect release version (use '--releasever' to specify release version)
AlmaLinux $releasever - BaseOS                                                                                                                                 94  B/s | 153  B     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'baseos':
  - Status code: 404 for https://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/$releasever/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 67.222.0.50)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'baseos': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

This is happening for all [baseos], [appstream] and [extras] in the .repo file.

It seems I was missing the almalinux-release package, this was confirmed this by running rpm -V almalinux-release, which returned: package almalinux-release is not installed and solved it by running dnf --releasever=8 install almalinux-release
